# Modify passwords in an LDIF file using ldapmodify command

Tags: ldap, ldif

I have a LDIF file that consists of a set of test users and I would like to  change the passwords for these users.

I used the `ldapmodify` command:

```
ldapmodify -c -a -f filename.ldif -h localhost -p <port> -D dn -w <pwd> << !

dn: uid=<userid>,dc=<branch>,DC=COM
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: <new pwd>
!
```

And I get the following error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

1. What does this mean?
2. The syntax I have used can be used for only one user, I would like to modify the passwords of all the test users in my LDIF file. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The given error is an indication that the server specified by the hostname and port could not be contacted, that is, a connection could not be established. Also, the legacy OpenLDAP `ldapmodify` client defaults to a SASL bind when the `-x` command line option is not specified.

The LDIF input can contain any number of entries to be modified, not just one:

```
dn: uid=abc,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: the-new-password

dn: uid=def,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: another-new-password
```

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering ldapmodify](http://web.archive.org/web/20121111000428/http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Terry. Now I can understand how it works. When I add -x to my command I get the following error, "ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)"

Comment: Having gone through "Mastering ldapmodify", this is the command I am using, ldapmodify -x -h localhost -p 4444 -D 'cn=root' -w <pwd> -c -f /tmp.ldif and I get the following error "ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)"

Answer (score 1):

```
ldapmodify -p 389 -D "" -w -a -c v -f pwd.ldif
```

pwd.ldif has below

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: root-dn-pwd
root-dn-pwd: xxxxxxx
```