# how to import passwords only and update on ldap server?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, ldap, openldap

I want to update passwords [user's already existing in ldap] of the user by importing data from /etc/passwd & /etc/shadow

How to achieve this ?

I will give the overview of my setup.

- nodes user id & password managed by management node [xcat], ldap not used for this purpose.

We have imported the user's from management node to ldap server by following the below given steps:-

1. Copied /etc/passwd, /etc/group & /etc/shadow from management node.
2. `getent passwd > /tmp/passwd.out getent shadow > /tmp/shadow.out`
3. `cd /usr/share/migrationtools/ ./migrate_passwd.pl /tmp/passwd.out > /tmp/passwd.ldif`
4. `ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=aadityaldap,dc=com" -f /tmp/passwd.ldif`

Now we want to update the passwords frequently and keep the ldap server sync with out management node. please give me idea how to achive this.

I tried the same way i imported users into ldap but it gives me an error.

```
[root@iitmserver2 migrationtools]# ldapmodify -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=aadityaldap,dc=com" -f /tmp/passwd.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldapmodify: modify operation type is missing at line 2, entry "uid=pharthiphan,ou=People,dc=aadityaldap,dc=com"
```

Comment: Your ldif seems to be incorrect, you may find a valid LDIF example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036747/modify-passwords-in-an-ldif-file-using-ldapmodify-command

Comment: You have an LDIF syntax error, but this won't work anyway. The passwords aren't *in* /etc/passwd. Only a hash of them.